# How to selectively route traffic for one specified IP adddress through the VPN tunnel (not all traffic)?

Tags: vpn

Goal: To selectively route traffic over a VPN, so that general browsing/downloads goes via the normal primary connection, with my business VPN traffic going over the VPN.

I have tried a similar method mentioned [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/53839/selectively-route-vpn-traffic-how-do-i-determine-subnet-value), but no matter how I changed the details it didn't work.

The VPN works, I can connect and route all traffic over it, so that is not the issue.

Home IP: 192.168.34.X

IP from VPN: 192.168.1.X

IP's (via VPN) trying to access in the internal network: 10.4.X.X, 196.220.X.X

How to selectively route traffic for one specified IP adddress through the VPN tunnel (not all traffic)?

Comment: Shame I cannot comment for some reason --- this is not an answer but a follow-up. So before deleting it, please see my question here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/96071/how-to-route-only-parallels-over-vpn I would like to route my VM traffic (or just some specific public IPs) over my PPTP VPN, but (maybe because my settings are not manual) I cannot figure out the specifics. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Step 1, create two plain text files named ip-up and ip-down in /etc/ppp and make the two files executable:

```
$ sudo touch /etc/ppp/ip-{up,down}
$ sudo chmod +x /etc/ppp/ip-{up,down}
```

Step 2, modify the file **ip-up**, add the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
export PATH="/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin"

OLDGW=`netstat -nr | grep '^default' | grep -v 'ppp' | sed 's/default *\([0-9\.]*\) .*/\1/'`

if [ ! -e /tmp/pptp_oldgw ]; then
    echo "${OLDGW}" > /tmp/pptp_oldgw
fi

dscacheutil -flushcache
route add 10.4.0.0/24 "${OLDGW}"
```

Step 3, modify the **ip-down**, add the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
export PATH="/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin"

if [ ! -e /tmp/pptp_oldgw ]; then
        exit 0
fi

ODLGW=`cat /tmp/pptp_oldgw`

route delete 10.4.0.0/24 "${OLDGW}"
rm /tmp/pptp_oldgw
```

Comment: Tried this exactly as you outlined - it did not work. Still not able to access either of the webpages via the VPN only while other browsing is via default connection.

Any further thoughts?

Comment: The script is selectively not route traffic for specific IP.  Other than those IP, all route via VPN.  ip-up runs when you connect to VPN, the specific IP will add to your old route table (so not going through VPN).  ip-down runs when you disconnect from VPN.